# Google sheets ACL/authorization

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a job that writes to google sheet using one service account (say X), and a number of users write to their own sheets. Currently all sheets writes are done through this single service account X. We ask users to share their sheets with this service account. But now the issue is how to prevent user A writes to a sheet owned by user B.

I wonder what would be the more proper solution. Will X impersonate as the user be a good solution? Or is there any other ACL functionality that Google Sheets API provides? Or any other suggestions.